# How can i track the progress of a function in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have a function written in C++ and compiled into a DLL. The DLL is then imported into a C# program and the function is called.

The C++ function processes files which can take a while so i was looking for a way to track the progress of the function.

I was thinking i could pass a pointer to a float to the function, run the function in a thread from C# and then print the value of the float:

C++ function:

```
void process(float *status)
{
    //process file code
    //............//

    *status = processed / total * 100;
}
```

And then in the C# code:

```
static extern void process(float *status);

int Main()
{
    float status = 0;
    
    thread.start(process(&status));

    while(status != 100)
    {
        Console.Write(status);
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that i cannot pass a pointer to a thread as an argument.

How can i achieve this??

Comment: Do you need a native c++ dll. Or can you convert the project to target c++/clr?

Comment: You would need some atomic types, or other synchronization mechanism to avoid data race.

Comment: It is a native c++ dll

Answer (score 0):

If you own the C++ code, you can replace the `status` variable with a callback.

If not, you can just make the local variable for status a global one you like this:

```
volatile float status;

void ThreadWorker() 
{
    process(ref status);        
}

int Main() 
{
   Thread t = new Thread(ThreadWorker);
   t.Start();

   while(status != 100)
   {
      Console.Write(status);
   }
}
```

Comment: how can i do the above in c#?

Comment: The above is in C#. :-)

Comment: Oh ok, i was saying that because there is no volatile keyword in c#

Comment: There is. You can use it for fields only, though, not for local variables.